# UITableView: Application crashing in attempt of deleting a row

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can any body tell me how can I achieve this. I want to delete a row from tableview with animation. Here goes my sample code

```
    [section0ARR removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:section inSection:row];
    [myTableVEW beginUpdates];
    [myTableVEW deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [myTableVEW endUpdates];
```

Application crashes while attempting this with this assertion **Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046**

but things work perfectly fine if I simply reload my table but in that case animation is not visible.

Here is a checklist

1. removed item from datasource

   1. deleted row from tableview with animation

please help me to get rid of the crash.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: Have u checked for `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: @Invincible yupp I checked that its as expected I tracked my code till there it crashes after that

Comment: Tried using `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @Invincible when you use "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths" it doesnt goes to commitEdittingStyle method

Comment: Hmm.. What is on line 1046 in that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
 NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:section inSection:row];
```

To this:

```
 NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
```

(I'm assuming that `row` and `section` are valid values since we don't have the rest of the code.)

Comment: That was a mistake, yes you soled the prroblem